# Check if Dictionary contains key by comparing with different type

Tags: c#, collections, equals, iequalitycomparer, equals-operator

So what I want to do is this

```
var result = dictionary.ContainsKey(Guid.Empty);
```

Where dictionary is defined as `var dictionary = new Dictionary<FooKeyClass, int>();`

Right now `FooKeyClass` is basically just some data with a public property of type `Guid`.
I have tried to override Equals, I've tried writing my own `IComparer`, I've tried to inherit `IEquatable<Guid>`. What ever I do I can't seem to get the desired functionality. Can someone please tell me if this even is possible in C# and if so how do I go by implementing it?

Here is the rest of the code, its kinda bloted with overrides as it is now though:

```
public class FooKeyClass : IEquatable<Guid>
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Guid guid)
    {
        if (guid == null)
            return false;
        return Guid.Equals(guid);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        var p = obj as FooKeyClass;
        if ((object)p == null)
            return false;

        return p.Guid.Equals(this.Guid);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(FooKeyClass a, Guid b)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
            return true;

        if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
            return false;

        return a.Guid.Equals(b);                
    }

    public static bool operator ==(FooKeyClass a, FooKeyClass b)
    {            
        if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
            return true;

        if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
            return false;

        return a.Guid.Equals(b.Guid);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(FooKeyClass a, FooKeyClass b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(FooKeyClass a, Guid b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Guid.GetHashCode();
    }
}

/// <summary>    
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<FooKeyClass, int>();

        var savedGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var tmpKey = new FooKeyClass() { Guid = savedGuid, Name = "feeefeee" };
        dictionary.Add(tmpKey, 42);

        var result = tmpKey.Equals(savedGuid); // no error
        result = tmpKey == savedGuid; // no error 

        result = dictionary.ContainsKey(savedGuid); // compile errror
        result = dictionary.Contains(savedGuid); // compile errror
        result = dictionary.Contains<Guid>(savedGuid); // compile errror

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of overhead, not to mention it seems to be the wrong approach.  If you were to go to all this effort, wouldn't it simply be easier to wrap the dictionary in a custom dictionary class of your own making and expose a different ContainsKey method that does what you are looking for? As is, you are masking intent.  It does NOT Contain the key at all, it just may contain an object that contains your key.  I'd recommend attacking the problem from a different angle.

Comment: Ye, you're probably right. Just my stubbornness overcoming my rational thinking while coding late in the afternoon. Wrapping dictionary in a custom dictionary with the additional desired functionality sounds like a more sane approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two primary options are the following:

1. Use the `Guid` to create an instance of `FooKeyClass` that you use as the actual key:

   ```
   var result = dictionary.ContainsKey(new FooKeyClass(Guid.Empty));
   ```
2. Change the type of your dictionary to `Dictionary<Guid, int>`.

If you frequently use `Guid.Empty` as the key for some particular purpose, you can create the equivalent key `FooKeyClass.Empty` so you don't have to keep creating new instances of it.

Note that since your `FooKeyClass` is used as the key for a dictionary, you should make sure the result of your `GetHashCode` method cannot change after an instance is created. In your current implementation, if you set the `FooKeyClass.Guid` property after the key is added to a dictionary, the entry in the dictionary will be "lost" because the hash code changes. This situation is automatically avoided if you use `Guid` instead of `FooKeyClass` as the keys of your dictionary, or you can remove the setter for the `FooKeyClass.Guid` property and require the user to use a constructor instead.

Comment: The Guid of an object should never change, that is my intention at least and the Guid will never be empty. Thats only in theory though and what I'm striving for.

Comment: I supposed that `Dictionary<Guid,Tuple<FooKeyClass, int>>` also is a plausible solution.